Why does the Egyptian Hieroglyph M8 (pool with lotus flowers) phonetically correspnd to 'Sh' sound?
DISCLAMER: I am an amateur researcher, very new to the topic.
I see in https://www.coptica.ch/Gardiner-EgyptianGrammar.pdf (page 480 , pdf page 516), that the M8 hieroglyph (pool with lotus flowers) corresponds to the Š3 (Sh) sound. The paragraph says "Hence phon. Š3...", but I don't understand the logic behind that "hence". Is it an onomatopoeic principle (a pool may sound like "shhhhh"), or some other reason? Do linguists actually know why it corresponds to sound Sh? Also that "3" in "Š3", is it a specific variation of the "Sh" sound?
I understand it's probably a very deep question. If you don't know the answer, maybe you could point me to a good source to figure it out?
Thank you very much!

To bring some of the clarifications from the comments here:
The lotus pool sign indicates the two consonants š ꜣ in Middle Egyptian, or approximately /ʃ ʔ/ in IPA. It's known as a "biliteral" sign because it indicates a sequence of two consonants, as opposed to e.g. the owl sign, which is a "uniliteral" for the single consonant m.
In later Egyptian, the ꜣ consonant generally disappeared entirely, so the lotus pool was used for just š on its own.
The reason it indicates the two consonants š ꜣ is because those are the consonants of the Middle Egyptian word for "swamp". In Egyptian, the vowels in a word can change to indicate different inflections, while the consonants generally stay the same. When you draw a picture of something, it's not always clear which inflection it is—a knife on a whetstone probably means "sharpen", but is that máádas "to sharpen", or madsá "might sharpen", or máádis "sharpening", or mádsiu "sharpened"? The one thing that's consistent between all these forms is the consonants, so the knife on a whetstone hieroglyph means the consonants m d s, no matter which vowels go between them.
Why is that the Middle Egyptian word for "swamp"? It evolved, just like most words do. But we don't know very much about the ancestors of Egyptian so it's hard to track the precise details.
This is the reason why most hieroglyphs have their pronunciations. Some Greek sources explain that the Egyptian word for "mother" is written with a vulture hieroglyph because of a myth about vultures being the ultimate mothers, who will feed their young with their own blood. But that's not actually the case; "vulture" and "mother" just have the same consonants in Egyptian, so you can use the vulture sign to write those consonants in the word for "mother". (The similarity in the words is probably why the Egyptians had myths linking vultures to motherhood; same for "come into being" and "scarab beetle", and so on. Ancient Egyptians loved this sort of pun.)

Thanks a lot for the answer! It indeed answers most of the questions I had after the first answer. I upvoted your answer, but with my current rank, my vote cannot yet be displayed.

It says  is an ideogram for the Egyptian word šꜣ, meaning 'lotus pool' or 'meadow', and hence it is also used for the phonetic value šꜣ.
ꜣ isn't actually a 3; it's the Egyptological alef, which is a separate letter (today conventionally read as [ɑ]).

may be worth clarifying that the "the phonetic value šꜣ" actually phonetically represents š(V)ꜣ(V) (where V is any vowel), as hieroglyphs (including multiliteral signs) generally did not mark vowels

So "šꜣ" is basically the transcription of the glyph which reads smth like "sh(V)a(V)"? Does that mean that it can't be used to represent an individual phoneme "Sh"? I read on wiki that in the Demotic script, this glyph became an alphabetic symbol that represented an individual phoneme "Sh". Was it different in the Egyptian script?

The main question I am actually curious about is: where the connection between that symbol that later evolved into Demotic and Coptic letters and the sound "sh" came from? I guess if the glyph used to read as "sh(V)a(V)", it makes sense why it would become "Sh" later, but do linguists know why it was pronounced as "sh(V)a(V)" in Egyptian in the first place?

@sd1074 when Cairnarvon says it is conventionally read as [ɑ] they are referring to the Egyptological pronunciation, which is a purely conventional way of reading Ancient Egyptian aloud for practical purposes. When I say š(V)ꜣ(V) I am referring to the reconstructed pronunciation (and, whilst the pronunciation of š is fairly clear, the pronunciation of ꜣ is much less so and had significant variation across time and, probably, between dialects). In the Egyptological pronunciation šꜣ would always be read as [ʃɑ], but this is not indicative of the historical pronunciation

when I say the pronunciation of ꜣ was more complicated, I mean that, at various stages and locations it may have been pronounced any of [ʀ], [r], [l], [ɫ], [j], or nothing at all (likely universal by Late Egyptian). It certainly was not historically pronounced as a vowel, that reading is purely one of modern convenience

Ok, it's interesting to learn about the Egyptological alef, but I am still not understanding several things 1) In the Egyptian language, could one hieroglyph represent a single phoneme, not just complete words/ideograms? I see that in Demotic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demotic_(Egyptian)), it's defeinitely the case: simplified hieroglyphs were used as uniliteral signs, each representing an individual phoneme/sound, similar to the modern alphabet


If, yes, do I understand correctly that the "lotus pool" [ʃɑ] glyph represented the sound "Sh"? I see again that in Demotic the phoneme for the simplified "louts pool" glyph is "Sh", but I don't know if "lotus pool" could have a similar role in Egyptian.



Do linguists have any theories to explain why ideograms were pronounced the way they were. Like we know that Mom/Mama in many languages pronounced similar because these are the easiest sounds to make by an infant. We know that "boom"  resembles the actual sound of a boom. Specifically, is there any theory explaining why "lotus pond" in Egyptian was pronounced as something like [ʃɑ]? My noob's guess/theory was that maybe the "Sh" sound is more or less universally associated with a quiet calm environment, such as a lotus pond. Just curious if there could be any truth to it.



most hieroglyphs in a given text are used phonetically, rather than for their meaning (although they typically can also be used logographically). Hieroglyphs used phonetically were like an abjad in that they only represented the consonants; a key difference however is that many hieroglyphs stood for more than one consonant, M8 is a so-called "biliteral" sign because it represents two consonants (which need not have formed a cluster, and could have an intervening vowel) when used phonetically



M8 represented two consonants at least into Middle Egyptian. By Late Egyptian the aleph sound had been lost, and so it represented a single consonant (probably followed by a long vowel resulting from the hiatus) which is why it came to be understood as uniliteral (representing a single consonant) in Demotic and later Coptic



what do you mean by ideograms? Such things have extremely marginal existence in any known writing system. Hieroglyphs could be used logographically but there they represent words. The hieroglyph of a lotus pond is pronounced the way it is because that's the way the word for a lotus pond is pronounced (and that hieroglyph could represent those consonants in other words following the rebus principle). The script is a red herring


Thanks a lot for the clarifications, now it makes sense to me. Your explanation on how the biliteral sign became uniliteral was particularly helpful. Maybe I should have said "logogram" or " hieroglyph" instead of "ideogram". I very much appreciated this opportunity to learn something from an expert.

I have rolled back vectory's edit as it was so confusingly worded as to not add extra information. It was also incorrectly labelled as fixing a typo

Hieroglyph M8  "pool with lotus" had a reading identified relatively early by scholars, as it was used in the cartouches of Persian kings Darius the Great (as well as subsequent kings named Darius) and Xerxes I, both of whose names in Old Persian cuneiform have  <š>.
